# Programa para comprobar si el input capturo un numero

Tags: matlab

He estado trbajando con Matlab un lenguaje nuevo para mi y lo que quiero realizar es un programa que se introduzca una calificacion y si esta es mayor a 6 muestre un mensaje de que paso de lo contrario que repruebe, pero tambien quiero hacer una comprobacion en donde si el usuario captura una letra o una palabra diga que se requiere capturar un numero y se detenga la ejecucion.

```
cali=input("Dame tu calificacion \n",'s');if cali2>6
fprintf("Felicidades pasaste");elseif cali2<=5
fprintf("Reprobaste");else
fprintf("Tienes que introduccir un numero");end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de probar varias veces este codigo me sirvio:

```
cali=input("Dame tu calificacion \n",'s');if str2num(cali)
cali2=str2num(cali);
if cali2>6
fprintf("Felicidades pasaste");
elseif cali2<=5
fprintf("Reprobaste");
end else fprintf("Tienes que introduccir un numero"); end
```

Supungo que hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo